# UTF-8 error in pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown + latex document that has compiled fine, until now when I added a special character ('ä') and get the error:

```
 hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid UTF-8 byte sequence)
```

Following some advice I've found I have tried combinations of these in a custom preamble, but with no success:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % also tried [utf8x]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

The full preamble is:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.8cm,lmargin=3.5cm,rmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}  
\usepackage[all,error]{onlyamsmath}
\MakeRobust{\overrightarrow}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{13.3pt}\selectfont}
```

pandoc call:

```
pandoc -f markdown file.mkd -H standard.tex --csl=amnat.csl --bibliography refs.bib -o output.pdf
```

Comment: pandoc is expecting utf8 input. Are you sure your file.mkd is in utf8? (file -i file.mkd to check it)

Comment: @JJoao Yes, after posting my question I found out that this was indeed the problem (it was in ascii). Didn't think about checking this first, since everything worked fine before, even with some advanced formatting. Post an answer calling for format check/conversion and I'll accept it.